# HTMLTextWriter Remove Hyperlinks and formatting in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmltextwriter

Some of my fields get exported as hyperlinks and I want it to format to standard font and remove hyperlinks. How do I do that in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used regular expression to remove the javascript behind the column which sorted it out.

```
string html2 = Regex.Replace(sw.ToString(), @"(<input type=""javascript""\/?[^>]+>)", @"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
html2 = Regex.Replace(html2, @"(<a \/?[^>]+>)", @"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Response.Write(html2.ToString());
```